# Can't create Quartz.NET Scheduler in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, quartz.net

After upgrading my Application to ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET 4.5), I get the following error when creating a Scheduler client:

> Type 'System.Web.HttpContextWrapper' in Assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

The exception is thrown here:

```
var sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
var sched = sf.GetScheduler();
```

The Web.Config:

```
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteClient" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="5" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy" value="true" />
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy.address" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:555/QuartzScheduler" />
</quartz>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz.NET should definitely work inside ASP.NET (MVC) application with .NET 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5.  There should be no place where HTTP context would be serialized.

- Check other lib issues, for example [Glimpse has had trouble with this earlier](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/632)

Comment: I'm using the latest version from NuGet: "<package id="Quartz" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />". There is no 4.5 build in the package, only net35 and net40. Should I build it from source?

Comment: I seem to have been low on caffeine, there isn't such a library version as 4.0 works fine with .NET 4.5, sorry. I'm running 2.2.1 with ASP.NET MVC 5 without any problems problems.

Does removing remoting proxy change anything?

Comment: I've built a new MVC 5 project and, as you said, it works fine with Quartz.NET 2.2.1. Maybe some issue after migrating from MVC 4 to 5. I'll try to find out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the problem was with Glimpse: I've uninstalled and now it's OK!